# How do you write Radio Button values to a Sql Database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, vb.net, asp-classic

I've been trying to write to my database and it's nearly complete the only problem Im having is with the radio values as there are two question asked within the webform both with a response of Yes or No. I found an example of this on stackover flow which was

```
Dim rbval As Integer
If RadioButton1.Checked Then
    rbval = 1
Else
    rbval = 2
End If
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ethics", SqlDbType.Int))
cmd.Parameters("@ethics").Value = rbval
```

But it didn't work and kept providing me with an error message and highlighting the cmd.ExecuteNonQuery section of the code. I then tried to play with it and put in:

```
Dim rbval As Integer
        If RadYes0.Checked Then
            rbval = 1
        Else
            rbval = 2
        End If
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@TeaAndCoffee", SqlDbType.Text).Value = RadYes0.Text
```

And it did work when I selected "Yes" but when I selected "No" the Yes value kept storing in the database and I can see where I went wrong from the code because its always going to select yes from the one I tried to fix. I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions? below is the full code

```
   Dim Con As SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand
    Dim recordsAffected As String
    Dim cmdstring As String = "INSERT [Event Table](EventTypeID, EventName, VenueName, NumberOfGuests, Date, ClientAddress, WeddingName, BuildingAddress, Canapes, Starter, MainCourse, Dessert, TeaAndCoffee) Values(@EventTypeID, @EventName, @VenueName, @NumberOfGuests, @Date, @ClientAddress, @WeddingName, @BuildingAddress, @Canapes, @Starter, @MainCourse, @Dessert, @TeaAndCoffee)"
    Con = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\YellowDoor.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
    cmd = New SqlCommand(cmdstring, Con)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@EventTypeID", SqlDbType.Text).Value = EventTypeDD.SelectedValue
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@EventName", SqlDbType.Text).Value = EventNametxt.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@VenueName", SqlDbType.Text).Value = VenueLoDD.SelectedValue
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@NumberOfGuests", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(NumOfGtxt.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(DateTxt.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ClientAddress", SqlDbType.Text).Value = txtAddress.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@WeddingName", SqlDbType.Text).Value = txtWedding.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@BuildingAddress", SqlDbType.Text).Value = txtBAddress.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Canapes", SqlDbType.Text).Value = txtCanapes.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Starter", SqlDbType.Text).Value = txtStarter.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@MainCourse", SqlDbType.Text).Value = txtMainCourse.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Dessert", SqlDbType.Text).Value = txtDessert.Text
    Dim rbval As Integer
    If RadYes0.Checked Then
        rbval = 1
    Else
        rbval = 2
    End If
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@TeaAndCoffee", SqlDbType.Text).Value = RadYes0.Text


    Con.Open()

    recordsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
    Con.Close()
    Response.Redirect("MenuForm.aspx")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your table column type in your SQL database. If it's a bit (the most logic way) it's as simple as a pie:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Yourparam", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = IIf (Radyes0.Checked,1,0)
```

For Char type:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Yourparam", SqlDbType.Char).Value = IIf (Radyes0.Checked,"Y","N")
```

For NVarchar type:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Yourparam", SqlDbType.Nvarchar).Value = IIf (Radyes0.Checked,"Yes","No")
```

A simple look at your table design will tell you whichever sentence you need. Use always the same datatype of your database.

By the way: The reason because this example

```
Dim rbval As Integer
    If RadYes0.Checked Then
        rbval = 1
    Else
        rbval = 2
    End If
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@TeaAndCoffee", SqlDbType.Text).Value = RadYes0.Text
```

Always saved Yes to your database, is because radiobutton.text gives the text label of the radiobutton, I believe you had a radiobutton for yes and a radiobutton for no, right?

Comment: I set it as text in the table what would be the best way?

Comment: Then, the same as nvarchar, but with text type. For boolean I would use a bit

Comment: The truth is that saving a boolean as text type in your database is the worst choice. A single boolean value weights very little but, text type reserves a lot of space for storing usually large comments, so if your table is large you are wasting a lot of space.

Comment: If my answer was useful to you and your problem is solved, please click the tick mark under my answer to award me and to make the solution clear for other users who may browse a similar problem.